# Improving WCF performance

Tags: wcf, web-services, soap

Could I know ways to improve performance of my .Net WCF service?
Right now its pretty slow and sometimes it gets clogged & eventually stops responding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of InstanceContextMode and ConcurrencyMode are you using on your service class?

If it's PerCall instances, you might want to check if you can reduce the overhead of creating a server instance for each call.

If it's Single instances (singleton) - do you really need that? :-) Try using PerCall instead.

Marc

Answer (score 2):

Well, what sort of data are you sending, and over what binding?

Is the problem the *size* of requests (bandwidth), or the *quantity* of requests (latency). If latency, then simply make fewer, but bigger, requests ;-p

For bandwidth: if you are sending binary data over http, you can enable MTOM - that'll save you a few bytes. You can enable compression support at the server, but this isn't guaranteed.

If you are using .NET to .NET, you might want to consider [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/); this has WCF hooks for swapping the formatter (`DataContractSerializer`) to use google's "protocol buffers" binary format, which is very small and fast. I can advise on *how* on request.

Other than that: send less data ;-p

Answer (score 1):

What binding are you using? If you're using HTTP you could get better perfomance with TCP.

In all likelihood though the bottleneck is going to be higher up in the WCF pipeline and possibly in your hosted objects.

We'd need some more details about your WCF set up to be able to help much.

Answer (score 0):

The symptoms you describe could be caused by anything at all. You'll need to narrow it down by using a profiler such as JetBrain's dotTrace or Automated QA's AQTime.

Or you could do it the old fashioned way by instrumenting your code (which is what the profilers do for you). Collect the start time before your operation starts. When it finishes, subtract the start time from the curren time to determine the elapsed time, then print it out or log it or whatever. Do the same around the methods that this operation calls. You'll quickly see which methods are taking the longest time. Then, move into those methods and do the same, finding out what makes *them* take so long, etc.

Answer (score 0):

"Improve performance of my .Net WCF service" - its very generic term you are asking, different ways we can improve performance and at the sametime you need to find which one causing performance hit like DB access in WCF methods.

Please try to know available features in WCF like oneWay WCF method it will help you in finding ways to improve performance.

Thanks
Venkat

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article with some statistics from real production systems, you could use these to compare/benchmark your performance.

[WCF Service Performance](http://hubpages.com/_1k9ore6as3b3m/hub/WCF-Service-Performance)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft recently released a knowledge base article:

- [WCF Performance and Stability Issues - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982897](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982897)

> These issues include the following: 
>   Application crashes
>   Hangs
>   General performance of the application when calling WCF Service.